# Do you know any plugins which allow marks to be longer than one char?

Tags: mark

I'm looking for plugin which emulates marks behavior for longer key sequences. I want to be able to mark two distinct files with 3 char mappings and jump to files when sequence is typed. Do you know if it already exists or is part of some other plugin? I couldn't find anything and consider building it myself.

Comment: I don't know such a plugin but I think it would be great to know why you want to do such a plugin? Are you already aware of the difference between `'a` and `'A`? Do you need more than 26 global marks plus 26 buffer local marks? Also did you look at [this plugin](https://github.com/MattesGroeger/vim-bookmarks) maybe it could be helpful.

Comment: Also, welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Yes I'm aware but problem is that its hard to remember 10 distinct mappings and where they lead to. Eg. I have 4 files: auth, assets, test_auth, test_assets. How to assign usual one key marks the way its easy to remember?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't find any plugin which emulates this behavior so I created one myself. If you are interested in such kind of behavior please check https://github.com/matmarczak/vim-longmarks.